# ASP.NET MVC filter by dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm writing a project in ASP.NET MVC, I'm trying to filter what I display by a selection in a  but cannot find how to save the selection.

```
<select >
    <option value = -1 >Any</option>
    @foreach(var c in ViewData["Categories"] as List<Category>)
    {
        <option > @c.CategoryName </option>
    }

</select>
```

I want to save the category that is selected so I can write something along the lines of

```
if(c.CategoryName == model.CategoryName)
```

This is what I want to filter

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnimalName)
            </td>
          
            <td>
               <img  height = "100" width = "100" src= @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Picture) >
            </td>
        
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName)
            </td>
            <td>
              
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.AnimalId">Details</a> 
             
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: It has been a while since I've done razor pages, but I think you will need to have some sort of state/variable that you set the `CategoryName` that the user selects and then you just filter based on that.

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter data in `@foreach (var item in Model) {`  when change the selected value?If so,you can try to use a partial view.

Answer (score -1):

For basic usage you can implement `@Html.DropDownListFor`, have a look at the [Official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) or [this tutorial](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-Bind-DropDownList-from-ViewModel-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx).